# i need to create 2 function distanceTravelled and kmToMileOutput in main()

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.10

i need to creat a functions distanceTravelled and kmToMileOutput in main() to ask for 5 float inputs from the user to get a list. Then, iterate through the list and convert each element to miles. Then, print the resulting list.

example

#Enter distance in KM: 2

#Enter distance in KM: 5.5

#Enter distance in KM: 1

#Enter distance in KM: 4

#Enter distance in KM: 8

#[2.0, 5.5, 1.0, 4.0, 8.0]

#Converted output:  [1.2428, 3.4177, 0.6214, 2.4856, 4.9712]

```
#So far this is my code. # is my code correct?

    def kmToMileOutput(distance_covered):
        miles = distance_covered * 0.621371
        return miles
    
    
    def distanceTravelled():
        lst = []
        for i in range(5):
            ele = float(input("Enter distance in Km: "))
            lst.append(ele)  # adding the element
        print(lst)
        lst2 = []
        for list in lst:
            x = list * 0.621371
            lst2.append(x)
        print("Converted output:",lst2)
    
    
    def main():
         distanceTravelled()
         kmToMileOutput(2)
    
    main()
```

Comment: seams homework assignment, study puthon

Comment: did you have a question?  It looks like you have already achieved your task...

Comment: i got it thanks for the help good citizen of StackOverflow!!